# Data is null when I retrieve from ajax call but working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ajax method to retrieve data. It is working in IE but I am getting data as null in FF and Google chrome.
I think the problem is, mozilla cant get 'data', because alert(data) returns null; even when I debug in firebug it is showing data is null.

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myserver.com/idpwd.asmx/idpwd",
        data: "{ 'userID': '" + $("#usrid").val() + "','password': '" + $("#password").val() + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Success,
        error: Error
    });
```

Comment: Try console.logging "{ 'userID': '" + $("#usrid").val() + "','password': '" + $("#password").val() + "' }"

Comment: I'm guessing you're hosting the page from the filesystem, or from localhost, right?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am using firebug to debug javascript.When I check "{ 'userID': '" + $("#usrid").val() + "','password': '" + $("#password").val() + "' }" in the watch window it is showing data. But when passing it to another  function it is becoming null. But in IE it is working perfect. @ patrick are  you talking about the web service or the page? I am testing the page from client browser.

Comment: @alienavatar - I'm talking about the page. Is the page hosted on a server or on your local machine?

Comment: The web service that i am calling and the page is hosted that I am testing are in the same domain. But I am testing from general client machine. But why it is working in IE if there is cross domain issue?

Comment: Some browsers will allow you to do a cross domain request if the page is being hosted from the filesystem or perhaps `localhost`. So if the URL in the location bar points to a page in the filesystem or localhost, then that may be why it works in some browsers and not others. Firefox and Chrome specifically are more strict in *not* allowing cross domain requests.

Comment: I suggest FF debugging with firebug and see whats being returned by the service, that will surely give you a better picture.

Comment: @Ajaxe - In the question, OP stated *"I debug in firebug It is showing data is null"*. This is typically what happens in a cross-domain request. You get a successful, yet null, response.

Comment: Yeah I am entering into Success function but the passing value of 'data' is null. I guess it is the issue with cross domain..Thank you all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I notice here:

- Your JSON string is not valid. Key/Value pairs need to have **double quotes**
- The hostname is probably not the same you're executing your ecma-/javascript

Comment: Thank you jAndy. Where should I double quote in the code? The web service that i am calling and the page is hosted that I am testing are in the same domain. But I am testing from general client machine. But why it is working in IE if there is cross domain issue?